# node.js Decipher AES 128 ECB

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, ecb

I try to decipher a base64 format token with AES 128-ecb on node.

**key**: ed9d26Z0JES0X52Q (changed some character, but a length is correct)

**token**: O4girrZ2YeLSE1sZ4FSIvp3Edm1GiwBLHmvDIEYCf+xkvbxP6EfYjy+PEB2kaYe0606EyPmlCC0iExVRq9e3Iw==

```
  decodeToken(token) {
    var key = new Buffer(exchangeKey, 'hex')
    var encrypted = new Buffer(token, 'base64')
    decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, '')
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false)
    result = decipher.update(encrypted).toString();
    return result;
  }
```

gives:

> crypto.js:239   this._handle.initiv(cipher, toBuf(key), toBuf(iv));
>                  ^
>
> Error: Invalid key length
>       at Error (native)
>       at new Decipheriv (crypto.js:239:16)
>       at Object.Decipheriv (crypto.js:236:12)

After some searching I found this:

```
// https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/4744#issuecomment-25460050
var aesEcb = new MCrypt('rijndael-128', 'ecb')
aesEcb.open(exchangeKey);
var ciphertext = new Buffer(token, 'base64');
var plaintext = aesEcb.decrypt(ciphertext).toString();
return plaintext
```

what gives back

**f9712fa5-da4a-49fe-b81f-b48d8cfabf91275RAODW24RS**

what looks like the expected format and length, but notice the wired characters at the end.

I could use this solution too (and trim the extra characters), but I want to

- know what are those characters
- cross reference the two results
- use only one npm package (crypto)

Comment: Do not use mcrypt, it doesn't support PKCS5 padding.  Additionally, I know it sounds shocking, but the reason you are getting an invalid key length error is because the key is of invalid length *gasp*.  Your key is 8 bytes long, AES requires a minimum key size of 16 bytes.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark that key I received, and mcrypt gives a kind a correct result with my 8bytes key.

Comment: If the key is literally the raw hex characters then why are you decoding it as hex in your first code excerpt...?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark because I am blind :) Thanks, it works now, and it gives the same result. What is good, but on the other hand I still have those ugly characters.

Comment: Because you aren't using padding...

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark you were right again. If you make an answer, I accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're decoding the key as hex when you intend to use the individual hex characters as the key bytes.  Don't do that.  You've also got padding disabled.  Enable padding to remove the weird characters.